# Analytic geometry problem

Tags: geometry

[image]
In the figure ABCD is a parallelogram and AE=EB if A (2,1) and C (-1,5) are given find coordinates of point P
Is there any particular theorem for this problem?

Comment: Is $ABCD$ a parallelogram?

Comment: Since we can only guess that this is a parallelogram or that $E$ is the midpoint of $AB$, this isn't really a mathematical problem. Please, add the missing information, and why you have a problem with such a simple exercise.

Comment: In your diagram it looks like A is left of C, but that's not so for the points A,C you give below the figure.

Comment: Yes it is a parallelogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let DB cut AC at F. Then, F is the midpoint of DB. Further, P is the centroid of the $\triangle ADB$.

Do you know AP : PC = ?

(Further hint -- AP : PF = 2:1 because P is the centroid of $\triangle ADE$ and AF : FC = 1 : 1 because F is the middle point of the the //gm ABCD.)

If yes, you can use the section formula to find P.

Comment: No AP:PC is not given

Comment: @Clair See Further hint.